# Floating css problem

Tags: css, css-float

this is my problem:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31659128/buildworx/site-v2/project/index.html

screenshot: [image]

I just can't seem to get this floated right.

```
 header, nav { margin: 0 auto 30px auto; width: 960px; }

header #ip-wrapper { float: right; width: 375px; }
header #ip-wrapper .ip-wrap { background: #636363; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%,rgba(58, 58, 58, 1) 100%); margin: 10px 0; border-radius: 20px 5px 5px 20px }
header #ip-wrapper .ip-wrap .ip-name { background: #e5e5e5; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(242,242,242,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); display: inline-block; padding: 10px 12px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; margin: 0 10px 0 0 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I don't get it.... what's the problem?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.  The logo server bits now line up.  Did you change something?

Comment: Looks good in Firefox ... what's the problem?  IE?

Comment: In the screenshot, when I float the right block it doesn't align....

Comment: You need to put `type="text/css"` attributes on your css links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float:left on your image.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="bw" style="float: left;">
```

Your #ip-wrapper is currently trying to float on the right of something that is an inline object. That's what's causing you problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the HTML5 `header` tag which older browser will not handle  properly, use a `<div class="header">` if you want to support older versions. Might wanna lose the `nav` and `footer` aswell.

Comment: Keep html5 tag, but make sure you have a fallback that will create the tags in older browsers. This one provided by google work great: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->